# Почему C# TcpListener нагружает процессор

Tags: c#, websocket, tcplistener

Делаю связку C# TcpListner + JS Websocket. Соединение устанавливается, данные передаются. Проблема в том что после установки соединения (handshaking) процессор загружается на 25% постоянно. Думаю что проблема в цикле while, но у меня есть еще HttpListener с таким же циклом и процессор не нагружается. Как решить проблему? Пример взял [отсюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server)

```
class TcpServer
{
    public string ip;
    public int port;
    private Thread bgThread;

    public void StartListen()
    {
        bgThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Start))
        {
            IsBackground = true,
            Name = "MyTcpListener"
        };
        bgThread.Start();

    }

    public void Start()
    {
        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
        server.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Server has started on {0}:{1}, Waiting for a connection...", ip, port);

        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine("A client connected.");

        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        while (true)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("loop");
            while (!stream.DataAvailable) ;
            while (client.Available < 3) ; // match against "get"

            byte[] bytes = new byte[client.Available];
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, client.Available);
            string strbytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

            if (Regex.IsMatch(strbytes, "^GET", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("=====Handshaking from client=====\n{0}", strbytes);

                // 1. Obtain the value of the "Sec-WebSocket-Key" request header without any leading or trailing whitespace
                // 2. Concatenate it with "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" (a special GUID specified by RFC 6455)
                // 3. Compute SHA-1 and Base64 hash of the new value
                // 4. Write the hash back as the value of "Sec-WebSocket-Accept" response header in an HTTP response
                string swk = Regex.Match(strbytes, "Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").Groups[1].Value.Trim();
                string swka = swk + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
                byte[] swkaSha1 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(swka));
                string swkaSha1Base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(swkaSha1);

                // HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker
                byte[] response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                    "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n" +
                    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" +
                    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" +
                    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + swkaSha1Base64 + "\r\n\r\n");

                stream.Write(response, 0, response.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("strbytes: " + strbytes);
                bool fin = (bytes[0] & 0b10000000) != 0,
                    mask = (bytes[1] & 0b10000000) != 0; // must be true, "All messages from the client to the server have this bit set"

                int opcode = bytes[0] & 0b00001111, // expecting 1 - text message
                    msglen = bytes[1] - 128, // & 0111 1111
                    offset = 2;

                if (msglen == 126)
                {
                    // was ToUInt16(bytes, offset) but the result is incorrect
                    msglen = BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[] { bytes[3], bytes[2] }, 0);
                    offset = 4;
                }
                else if (msglen == 127)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("TODO: msglen == 127, needs qword to store msglen");
                    // i don't really know the byte order, please edit this
                    // msglen = BitConverter.ToUInt64(new byte[] { bytes[5], bytes[4], bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[9], bytes[8], bytes[7], bytes[6] }, 0);
                    // offset = 10;
                }

                if (msglen == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("msglen == 0");
                else if (mask)
                {
                    byte[] decoded = new byte[msglen];
                    byte[] masks = new byte[4] { bytes[offset], bytes[offset + 1], bytes[offset + 2], bytes[offset + 3] };
                    offset += 4;

                    for (int i = 0; i < msglen; ++i)
                        decoded[i] = (byte)(bytes[offset + i] ^ masks[i % 4]);

                    string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", text);
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("mask bit not set");

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

**JS**

```
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.149:1112");
function startup() {
    var el =document.getElementById("mousePad");
    el.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);
    el.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, false);
    el.addEventListener("touchcancel", handleCancel, false);
    el.addEventListener("touchleave", handleEnd, false);
    el.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);
    log("initialized.");

    //socket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.149:1112");
    log("state: "+socket.readyState)
    socket.onopen = function(e) {
        log("state onopen: "+socket.readyState)
        log("[open] Соединение установлено");
    };

    socket.onclose = function (e) {
        log("DISCONNECTED");
    };

    socket.onerror = function(error) {
        log("[error]"+error.message);
    };
}
```

Comment: используйте вместо regex -> `str.StartsWith("GET")`

Comment: процессор не может так сильно нагружаться при 1-поточной работе. скорее всего проблема не в этом коде, а в коде за его пределами. найдите не нагрузку, а разницу [дельту/приращение/изменение] нагрузки, т. к. сама нагрузка ни о чём не говорит.

Comment: @return не помогло. да и не должно было. регэкс это же не тяжелая процедура. вне этого кода только старт сервера

Comment: ну как сказать, я делал замеры нормального парсера и regex (длина regex: 10) и обнаружил, что разница в 18 раз (конечно, в сторону парсера)! тут парсер это `StartWith` (`StartWith` – довольно не затратный метод)

Comment: да и `StartWith` тупо приятнее глазу видеть

Comment: и я вам же сказал: «найдите не нагрузку, а разницу [дельту/приращение/изменение] нагрузки, т. к. сама нагрузка ни о чём не говорит».

Comment: @return переведите пожалуйста про нагрузку

Comment: вот смотрите, до запуска процесса нагрузка была 20%, после запуска стала 25%. разница, или дельта, или приращение, или изменение равно 25% - 20% = 5%, т. е. ваш процесс нагрузил процессор на 5%, а не на 25%.

Comment: @return я разве писал что сначала было 20%? все 25% нагрузки идут от tcplistner'а и я не знаю как это победить

Comment: значит я вас не правильно понял (решил чекнуть все тривиальные случаи). я сам не знаю, что это за "аномалия". надо будет поискать в нете (возможно, и в зарубежном)

Comment: @return буду признателен если что нибудь выкопаете. я уже обыскался

Comment: вы точно знаете сколько, сколько потоков работает при запуске вашего процесса? обычно, на таких вещах вопрос и заканчивается, хотя что-то мне подсказывает... можете, ну не знаю, через диспетчер задач проверить)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109650/discussion-between-axmed2004-and-return).

Comment: не знаю, что вы там тестировали, но у меня как tcp, как socket, так и http работают с одинаковой нагрузкой на ЦП – 10-15% (у меня). я скопировал ваш код и прогнал его по 3-м вариантам. покажите, пожалуйста, вашу http реализацию

Comment: возможно, [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28991366) вам поможет

Comment: Нагружает не TclListener, а `while (!stream.DataAvailable) ;`. Почему не stream.Read?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight не знаю почему. Я сделал по статье указанной наверху. Я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в некоторых вещах, поэтому спрашиваю тут. Я просто хочу чтобы моя программа не нагружала процессор во время бездействия, хоть кто то и говорит что это нормально, я считаю что не нормально

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вы хотя бы небольшой sleep для начала в ваши циклы while добавьте, а то это же ад какой-то для процессора - гонять пустой бесконечный цикл:

```
while (!stream.DataAvailable)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
while (client.Available < 3)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Но лучше весь код как-то на async/await переписать, чтобы не гадать с периодом ожидания и чтобы было всё совсем хорошо и правильно.

Comment: хоть это и кажется мне костылем, но все же помогло. Хватило `Thread.Sleep(1);` в первом цикле. async await я добавил `public async void Start(){   }` и `if (await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, client.Available) > 0){   }` но это не помогло. но скорее всего причина в моих малых познаниях

Comment: С async надо практически все операции ввода-вывода на асинхронные переделывать, иначе и правда может не сильно помочь.

Comment: @axmed2004 А так то это не костыль, это нормально в эпоху до async/await отдавать хоть на время управление из своего потока во время ожидания, чтобы остальные потоки и GUI не тормозили.